# How to add values in a single array (for parsing)

Tags: php, arrays

So i am asking this cause i am parsing some data, and i place it in an array called 'cards'. If i `print_r($cards)` my output will be this:

```
[0] => The Hunt for Gollum
[1] => (x3)
[2] => The Hunt for Gollum
[3] => (x3)
[4] => The Hunt for Gollum
[5] => (x3)
[6] => The Hunt for Gollum
[7] => (x3)
[8] => The Hunt for Gollum
[9] => (x3)
[10] => The Hunt for Gollum
[11] => (x3)
[12] => The Hunt for Gollum
[13] => (x3)
[14] => The Hunt for Gollum
[15] => (x3)
[16] => The Hunt for Gollum
[17] => (x1)
[18] => The Hunt for Gollum
[19] => (x3)
[20] => The Hunt for Gollum
[21] => (x4)
[22] => The Hunt for Gollum
[23] => (x2/x0)
[24] => The Hunt for Gollum
[25] => (x3)
[26] => The Hunt for Gollum
[27] => (x2)
[28] => The Hunt for Gollum
[29] => (x2)
[30] => The Hunt for Gollum
[31] => (x2)
[32] => The Hunt for Gollum
[33] => (x2/x1)
[34] => The Hunt for Gollum
[35] => (x5/x2)
[36] => The Hunt for Gollum
[37] => (x2)
[38] => The Hunt for Gollum
[39] => (x2)
[40] => The Hunt for Gollum
[41] => (x3/x1)
```

---

And i am asking if you know a way so i can display this array like that : `[0]=>The Hunt for Gollum (x3)`, `[1]=>The Hunt for Gollum (x3)` etc... 
But with less code.. not reapeating myself `[47]` times Thnx

Comment: Have you made any efforts yourself so far?

Comment: @NigelRen i have searched the phpManual but didn't find anything yet. Is this possible to happen ? My question

Comment: How about trying a `for()` loop and incrementing the loop by 2 each time, using the loop to access the elements of the array?

Comment: i will go check it out right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new array like that :

```php
$array = ["The Hunt for Gollum", "(x2)","The Hunt for Gollum", "(x2)","The Hunt for Gollum", "(x2)"];
$newArray = [];
for( $i=0; $i < count($array) - 1; $i++ ){
    $newArray[] = $array[$i]. ' '. $array[$i+1];
    $i++;
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Try in online on [sandbox onlinephpfunctions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3861de8a4f1e5cdfb1e89611d59de40fad5db881)

Comment: actually working very good, one question cause i am getting Errors about `Undefined offset:` do you know what is this ?

Comment: Maybe your array isn't an even length. So it's my fault, just add -1 after the count ($array).

Comment: dame..good job thank you i will study your code to understand why you put this `- 1 ;` and worked without errors

Comment: he put `-1` because `count($array)` gives you the number of array elements, but the array index starts with 0 not with 1

Comment: Yes @ChrisG is right !
To go more in depth:
Imagine you have 3 element on your array: `array("one", "two", "tree")`. So without the -1, the conditions in for statement is as follow`$i  < 3`. So at the last turn $i is equal 2. If you try to get $array[$i+1]  ($array[3]) you got an undefinded index. Because array start at 0. So the last item of this array is $array[2].

Comment: More clear: `array(0 => "one", 1 => "two", 2 => "three")`